# Shouldn't questions with SO-link-only accepted answers be closed as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions, moderators

I recently raised two custom flags on two old answers where:

1. The answers were accepted.
2. The answers were merely links to other SO answers.

Questions can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004571/unable-to-change-url-for-net-reference-to-dynamic-web-service/3114555#3114555) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33181237/payload-contains-two-or-more-files-with-the-same-destination-path-sqlite3-dll/33198909#33198909) (Deleted answers will be visible only to 10k+ rep holding users).

The statements I made in the flags were:

> This is essentially a link to another SO answer. It should have been a
>   comment and this question should be closed as dupe of that one

and

> This answer is a link to another SO answer. It should have been a
>   comment and this question should be closed as dupe of that one as the
>   OP has marked it as correct answer

Since the respective OPs marked them correct, that means the links solved their problems and the questions were duplicates with same idea described in different words.

The flags were marked helpful and the answers were removed. However, the questions were left open by the mods and not marked as duplicate.

Shouldn't marking the questions as duplicate be the proper course of action here, so that in future, if any other reader lands on those pages, they would get a link to the correct answer?

Comment: If I had to guess, the mod figured you had CV privileges and should use them rather than having a mod proxy your vote.

Comment: I know these weren't my flags because I normally do the deed of marking the questions as duplicates along with deleting the answers.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Yes.

And I think the poster of the "answer" should get no reputation. Such "answers" are an abuse: they contribute nothing, but award reputation to the "answerer" for the work done by other people.

Comment: @NSNoob Heck yes. In fact I'd say getting the unwanted answers destroyed is the cleanup portion of this process, the closing as a dupe is the primary concern. but before that will happen, someone actually does need to properly flag/close vote and select a duplicate target. The "mod" in that process that needs to do it is you (and me, and anyone else that gives a hoot).

Comment: @Gimby I did flag one of them, As it didn't get closed and the vote expired I guess, I didn't bother with the next one seeing as they were really old questions :( It might be more effective if mods were to use their hammer to immediately close the question.

Comment: @NSNoob so the mods should also be responsible for picking the duplicate target, which requires domain knowledge?

Comment: @Gimby In case there is no accepted answer, nopes. If the question has a link-only accepted accepted answer which has to be removed, doesn't it make the target obvious? There is the link to it in the accepted answer

Comment: @NSNoob I get the intention and it would certainly speed things up quite a bit, but it is making a big assumption - that the link is in fact relevant enough. When someone flags a dupe several people have to agree with that before it is pushed through; in this hypothetical process one person posts a link as an answer - an answer in which little effort is invested, and then that one link immediately becomes the dupe target. I would always want to have a search for a better dupe target incorporated myself, so I will continue to rebel against the notion that a mod makes this happen ;)

Comment: @Gimby ... but if the OP accepts the posted link as the answer?  In that case the burden of agreement by mod committee can be reduced considerably.

Comment: If the same question were asked using different wording(key words,  question words, etc), it very much could effect whether search engines found the "answer" using a given query.  The ultimate goal is for the site to be helpful, and -finding- the answer is as important as the answer existing.  In terms of the "points",  I think more people are likely to give a +1 to the actual 'answer' and far fewer people will +1 a link to the answer in another post.  I suppose the ideal solution would be to delete the 'duplicate" but and add a "also asked as" field to the post with good answers in it.

Comment: Quoting Boltclock (One of our mods) from his comment from two days ago: `"I know these weren't my flags because I normally do the deed of marking the questions as duplicates along with deleting the answers"` . So it appears the at least some mods do proceed with this course of action.

Answer (score -2):

It depends.

And here is why: Some questions are clear duplicates of other questions. In other cases, the solution is applicable to a whole set of questions. The answer "Restart windows" might be applicable to two completely different questions and solve the problem in its respective context. It might be, that the answer is not specific enough, but someone asking one question, might not no nor understand, that this question might in its essence be linked with another one.

See my own, a little more specific, example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41486169/float32-overflow-in-numpy-arange).

Comment: Your answer is not a link only answer.  Yes, it has a link, but you provide some additional details as to why the answer applies to that question.  A true link only answer essentially says *"See this answer here: <link>"* with no additional information.  If it were truly link only, then it is more than likely going to be either a duplicate or a very bad answer.

Answer (score -11):

Mods are busy.  If there is a task you can do with the tools you have, use the tools.

In this case, I'd mark it as "duplicate of" using your existing powers.

You could also flag the accepted answer as a link-only answer.  But that is "just cleanup".  Really, someone earning 45 reputation "incorrectly" doesn't seem something I'd bother a mod with unless it was a serious systematic problem.

Personally, I'd close as duplicate, downvote the link-only answer, and move on.

Comment: This argument occasionally pops up on Meta, but I don't think it's a good one. If the moderators are too busy to, um, *moderate*, then we should elect more moderators.

Comment: The mods did find time to visit the said post and remove the said answer right? How much longer could it possibly take for them to close the post seeing as the OPs had marked those answers as accepted, therefore confirming them to be duplicates. As stated already, tools at my disposal aren't always effective. As I did cast a CV on one of them, it just expired.

Comment: @cod By that argument, every post and comment should be moderated by 10 mods who form a consensus about if it should appear in real time.  That is ridiculous (and a straw man/slippery slope), but more mods is a cost; you generally get worse ones (as ideally you pick the best ones first).  Managing more mods is a cost; the bigger the team, the more paperwork and rules, the less people talkimg to people.  On SO we can self moderate as users, and there is nothing here that is beyond our capabilities to self moderate; when there is no need to escalate, we should not.

Comment: @nsnoob At least 5-15 seconds to do it, plus an extra 5-15 seconds *on every moderator flag* to consider what additional actions should be done implied but not asked for by the flag.  Maybe another 30 seconds of task switching to go from one UI to another if they have a streamlined UI for handling flags.  If handling a flag like this usually takes 20 seconds on average and they spend 1 hour on it (so 180 flags) per day, this request might come to 45 seconds for this task plus 45 minutes/day * 365 days/year =~250 hours of slower flag processing?  Per moderator?  Just napkin math.

Comment: I'm baffled by this answer. This is a clear abuse of the system. We delegate our moderators to moderate on our behalf. This is a clear case of something that needs moderating. Of course mods should act on it.

Comment: @magi it is a year old post where someone doesn't know how to flag as duplicate which resulted in a tiny amount of "benefit" at worst.  Like I said, if systematic, I'd report; for one instance, I would downvote/comment/close as duplicate.  The harm is tiny, the evidence of "bad faith" lacking, the benefit from the bad act tiny.  If this was a pattern of the poster, **then** I'd flag and get a mod involved.

Comment: @CodyGray Moderators don't exist to handle all moderation on the site.  The site is specifically designed to be community moderated.  Moderators exist *to handle moderation problems that the community is unable to handle*, either because the problem is such that the community doesn't have the tools to handle it, or because the community is conflicted as to what to do.  From day 1 it's been known that it was beyond the scope of possibility for moderators to handle all moderation; that's why the site is primarily community moderated in the first place.

Comment: ...and deleting an accepted answer is one of the things the community can't do for itself. Then, once the answer's deleted, the duplication is much much harder to know about.